# Python and sqlite3 - importing and exporting databases

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I'm trying to write a script to import a database file.  I wrote the script to export the file like so:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('../sqlite.db')
with open('../dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for line in con.iterdump():
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Now I want to be able to import that database. I have tried :

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('../sqlite.db')
f = open('../dump.sql','r')
str = f.read()
con.execute(str)
```

but I'm not allowed to execute more than one statement.  Is there a way to get it to run an SQL script directly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
sql = f.read() # watch out for built-in `str`
cur.executescript(sql)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript).

Comment: @adam - I think you mean to create a cursor first if you copied that from the documentation ("cur.")

Comment: The sqlite3 module allows either usage; take your pick.

Comment: @adam - I am aware of that. But "cur" is not defined in the question code, right?

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to execute a lot of inserts?  I have a lot of them and it's too slow this way

Comment: There are some tips here: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuning The dump should already be wrapped in a transaction for you (to avoid opening and closing database between inserts).

Comment: @JPC try [executemany()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
con.executescript(str)
```

Documentation

```
Connection.executescript(sql_script)
    This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates an intermediate cursor object
    by calling the cursor method, then calls the cursor’s executescript
    method with the parameters given.
```

Or create the cursor first

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('../sqlite.db')
f = open('../dump.sql','r')
str = f.read()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(str)
```